# Django Rest Framework doesn't return Response code from condition

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return a 405 response from DRF if the object is not allowed to be deleted, but I keep getting a Response 204_NO_CONTENT. Even though the instance is not deleted and the if statement works as should, the returned response is not correct. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
def perform_destroy(self, instance):
    if not instance.deletable:
        return Response({'error_message': 'Cannot delete last journal entry line.'}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    sje_id = instance.journal_entry.id
    instance.delete()
    sje = PurchaseJournalEntry.objects.get(pk=sje_id)
    sje.regenerate_mutations()
    sje.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`perform_destroy`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) is not supposed to return a HTTP response. It simply is supposed to remove the object, not return a response. If you return a response, it is simply ignored.

You can override the [**`destroy`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroymodelmixin) function however, like:

```
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    if not instance.deletable:
        return Response({'error_message': 'Cannot delete last journal entry line.'}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    self.perform_destroy(instance)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 2):

`perform_destroy` is not supposed to return anything.

If you want to alter this, either you should override the view's `destroy` or raise the proper exception:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import MethodNotAllowed

def perform_destroy(self, instance):
    if not instance.deletable:
        raise MethodNotAllowed(default_detail='Cannot delete last journal entry line.')
    sje_id = instance.journal_entry.id
    instance.delete()
    sje = PurchaseJournalEntry.objects.get(pk=sje_id)
    sje.regenerate_mutations()
    sje.save()
```